# Is Green card priority date based on place of birth or citizenship?

Tags: usa, greencard, indian-citizens

As an Indian citizen, just wondering if its faster that I move to Denmark, stay for 9 years and get Danish citizenship. From there move to US on H1B and convert to green card.

This would be faster than waiting for the priority date for Indians

Comment: What's much of the point in moving to the US after living in Denmark for 9 years and becoming a citizen lol... Unless one gets some mega offer to earn tons of money one might as well stay in Scandinavia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The priority date is based on the place of birth of the applicant (or spouse, if they're different and the queue for one is shorter than the other). Moving/acquiring citizenship in another country doesn't affect it. See the [USCIS](http://www.uscis.gov/tools/glossary/foreign-state-chargeability):

> Chargeability is usually determined by country of birth. Exceptions
>   are made to prevent the separation of family members when the
>   limitation for the country of birth has been met.

Comment: Interesting.. (Not OP) does that mean if my 1 year younger brother was born in Dubai, it would be faster for him to go to US, get a green card and then sponsor me for a green card (me being an Indian born in India) compared to me applying for a GC by myself?

Comment: @user762 you'll still get stuck in the line for family based petitions, but it will indeed be faster for your brother.